# When using a dll library, is it necessary to include all of the headers used to build the dll?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have built a shared library (`.dll`) from a C++ source code.

Now when I want to use this library in another program, do I need to include all of the header files that were used originally for building the library, or including just the headers that belong to used functions in my (new) program suffices? There are many functions in the library that are not used **directly** in my new program, but, needless to say, all of them are used by the functions in the program.

(So they are indirectly used in the program too, and it would be strange if their inclusion is not necessary.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Header files are nothing magical, they're just a convenient way of ensuring your `.cpp` file has access to all the declarations and definitions it needs. So only include those you actually need in each of your files<sup>(1)</sup>.

The above refers to putting `#include` statements in your files—only do this for header files you actually need to use. Of course, the header files you include can `#include` other header files themselves.

Like any other well-behaved (i.e., actually usable) DLL, your DLL must supply a set of public interface header files. Under normal circumstances, you must have all these public interface header files available for building a program using that DLL. That doesn't mean you should `#include` them all; quite on the contrary, you should not. The compiler (preprocessor, actually) will `#include` what it needs.

Note that when the DLL itself was built, there were probably many more header files involved, but these were private to the implementation and not part of the public interface. You do not need them to build a program using the DLL, and in the general case you don't even have access to them.

So, when designing your own DLL, you must stricly differentiate between public and internal header files. The public header files must be made available to clients, the internal ones need not (unless the client is supposed to build the DLL themselves). Of course, this means a public header file may never `#include` an internal one.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that header file inclusion is purely textual—when reading your source file, the preprocessor effectively copies the contents of the header file and pastes it in place of the `#include` statement, then goes on parsing. You you did this copy & paste yourself instead, the file would build and run just as well. Of course, it wouldn't pick up later changes in the header file, which is the primary reason why header files are used in the first place.

Comment: But, many headers are included in the headers of the functions that I call (and include their corresponding header). How compiler knows about them?

Comment: @user215721 `#include` statements in the DLL's header files will be resolved just like any other `#include` statement. I will expand the answer a bit, maybe we're referring to different meanings of the word "include."

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your last sentence actually gave me the answer: *Of course, this means a public header file may never `#include` an internal one.* Now I have to make many of my headers internal by copy-pasting their code in place of `#include`s in other public ones.

Comment: @user215721 I don't think that's the right solution. It would be better to restructure your code and files so that internal things (types, functions etc.) are never referenced in public header files. The DLL's `.cpp` files and internal header files can happily `#include` both public and internal header files, of course.